# How can I enable correct port to use CURL from my EC2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, curl, amazon-ec2

I have created an EC2 instance in AWS. I can connect with the machine through SSH. Also, I have deployed test web app in apache and I am also able to access it from my laptop.

I am trying to use curl command from the EC2 instance.

In security group, I have enabled all traffic both inbound and outbound.
In NACL, I have enabled all traffic outbound. For Inbound, I enabled, HTTP, HTTPS for all destination and SSH from my laptop only.

With this config, I could not run curl. It is timing out with "Failed to connect on port".

But If I enabled ALL TCP port in the inbound, it is working. But I don't want to do that. How can I enable correct port to use CURL from my EC2?

Comment: You are running `curl` on your EC2 machine? connecting to which machine? Post your curl command? What NACL are you are referring to?

Comment: CURL https://www.google.co.in/  NACL configuration in AWS I'm referring.

Comment: There is no need to use NACL for something you can accomplish with security groups, which is almost everything.  If you're going to use NACL, you need to understand ephemeral ports and open them.

Comment: This needs to be the answer. Thank you so very much man.